# Using Rstudio to group numbers

Tags: r

I have numbers 1:100, but I need to group them into 3 lets say 1-30, 30-60 and 70-100. Doing it individually is easy but how to put them professionally in code,. Help using Rstudio.

Comment: Your grouping is not trivially mathematic, otherwise I was going to suggest `split(vec, (vec-1) %/% 30)` (assuming `vec <- 1:100`). Otherwise, `vec <- list(1:30, 30:60, 70:100)`, and you're doubling 30 and omitting 61-69.

Comment: ?findInterval or ?cut might help

Comment: Thank you, but more like I want to represent the digits between 1-30 as low, 31 to 60 as medium and 61 to 100 as high, whilst still making them all connected in the same code. Hopefully you understand what I mean.

Comment: See the “cut” function

Comment: Is the range 1:100 and its subsets just an example, or is it your actual data? If it's just an example: how do you want the numbers to be distributed over the groups?